# Block or redirect user based on remote address

Tags: .htaccess

What is the best way to block a user from a website based on a remote address. I know how to do it by IP by using .htaccess file, but it seems the user is using a dynamic IP all the time, however the ISP name is always the same:

> 178-137-129-00-kie.broadband.kyivstar.net

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Block the range of that ISP in a firewall on your machine, blocking all traffic from their range to port 80 or 443 (or alternative port if in use) to your machine.

Alternatively you can do it at script-level, if you use PHP or ASP for example.

Comment: P.S. According to whois records, the IP block assigned to that Ukranian cell provider is: 178.137.0.0/16. Most firewalls should allow that notation (CIDR) when you add a blocking rule.

Comment: I suspect that the user is attempting to exploit my server but am not sure how yet, however it always comes from different referring site. Possibly they span and use my site as return address... not sure yet.